# WCF IIS lifecycle, "ResponseTimeLeak"

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I've a WCFService installed on IIS that it's working in a very strange way.

If I execute the service on a local machine (W10-IntelI7-8CPU-16GbRAM) it works fast and response time is about 200-300ms (on Debug with log's activated), but when I install it on a TestServer (W12 on a virtual machine, 4CPU-8GbRAM) it works very bad, the response on the client is abot 2s.

So I've started to put traces and the elapsed time on my server code (WCF Service implementation) is about 10-20ms, so the execution of the adhoc code is very fast. So the problem must be on WCF, but If I activate [WCF tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing) the trace shows the same as my code:

- On messages.svclog: 15ms between request and response
- On trace.svclog: 3 activities executed on 15ms

But if I watch the IIS log, the time-taken field is 2046ms.

So, anyone knows where are going that 2 extra seconds on the server? Any idea of how to trace this time-leak on server?

Comment: When running on the TestServer is it only the first request that is slow or is it all of them?

Comment: The first is slower due to startup. I'm tracing the following requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found the bug, it was my fault: It was a call to an url (localhost) on global.asax, that it was bad configured and it last 2 seconds to respond erroneusly. A shot in the foot!

I've fixed it, configuring the right url, logging the error when it's bad configured and avoiding call at every request.